# Do I have to select new quirks?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

After a quest, I am usually presented with the option of clicking on the drama-happy-sad-face icon (see image) which unveils new quirks, sometimes good and sometimes bad. Do I have to click on those? I mean if I don't click on it and just continue to the hamlet, do the new quirks just stay hidden and inactive?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not get to choose which perks or quirks your heroes gain, and you don't get to choose not to reveal them. The lands around the Darkest Dungeon are cruel and unrelenting.

You *can* however, at some expense, have your heroes treated at the Sanitarium and to have a quirk removed through brutally efficient aversion therapy.

((**Note:** once a quirk becomes "locked in" as seen by the red skull in a red square in front of it, it becomes significantly more expensive to remove. With gold as scarce as it is, think carefully as to whether you feel the expense is worth your adventurers' sanity.))

Comment: @Oak Err... it looks like it answers the question to me.

Comment: I agree that this answers the question.  @Oak, have you played the game?  If not, I can see how you might think this is not enough information.

Comment: @Oak I don't see, what else I could say. the op asks, whether clicking "return to town" prevents quirks from being applied, the answer is no, as clicking return to town will do the same as clicking on the mask in the screenshot.

Comment: My mistake, hamlet as in town does answer it. My apologies

Comment: Thanks, definitely what happened. Was tired of gambling and failing (getting negative perks) if I didn't have to gamble it would have been worth it...